# How to resize angular cdk virtual viewport height when viewport size changes

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I'm working on Angular cdk virtual viewport. Is there any way to automatically adjust height of scroll viewport?

So in my case When viewport size increases there is a blank space displays at the bottom of viewport, this is the similar example for the reference

https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-mxahst?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `checkViewportSize` on the `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` which will align your viewport to the new dimensions.

First you take a reference to CdkVirtualScrollViewport in your component

`@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport, { static: true })`

Then after the size change you call `checkViewportSize` (After Button is clicked)

```
  public remove() {
    this.showBottomBar = !this.showBottomBar;
    setTimeout((x) => {
      this.cdkVirtualScrollViewport.checkViewportSize();
    }, 10);
  }
```

Note the little timeout, this is necessary because we want the dom changes (remove bottom-bar; render update) before we check the viewport size to align it.

Full example based on your Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-zl33lz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.scss

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```css
.page { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100px; 
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
   width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  padding: 0; 
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.page::after { 
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  top: 10px;
  right: -1px;
  width: 5px;
  background: #666;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
}
.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
    
.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: red;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
    background: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
    background: transparent;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
a<br/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Solution 2:

There're 2 sizes: with or without scrollbars. To get viewport size with scrollbars, use:

```
var viewportWidthWithScrollbars = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.offsetWidth; (change to innerHeight and offsetHeight for height)
```

innerWidth is for W3C browsers and offsetWidth for IE in standard mode.

To get the viewport size without scrollbars (that is what you probably need), use:

```
var viewportWidthWithoutScrollbars = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

the amount of vertial/horizontal scrolling

This is the tricky part. All browsers except for Chrome use documentElement.scrollLeft and Chrome (and IE in quirks mode) uses document.body.scrollLeft, so we have to check both values:

```
var pageScrollLeft = document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
```

Refer:

https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html